# The SVG backgrounf image is moving in Mobile view

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an icon as a svg, i used it as a background image, in desktop view it is overlapping with the label, Also when i try to minimize the screen it begin to move to the left how can this be solved?

**CSS**

```
info{
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  &::after {
    content: ""; 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../../assets/icons/info.svg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(38%) sepia(80%) saturate(823%)
      hue-rotate(162deg) brightness(92%) contrast(97%);
  }
}
```

```
<label className='info'>Data info available</label>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nwFP.png)

Comment: The issue is not directly reproducible from your code. It's not plain CSS/HTML and the SVG is not provided. It's extra work to answer your question. See question guidelines for future reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `background-position` with the value `right`.

When using relative values, `em` works better than percentages for responsive solutions, it ensures that the icon will be proportionally scaled up/down.

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info::after {
    content: ""; 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -1.5em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-image: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/342667/info.svg);
    background-position: right;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(38%) sepia(80%) saturate(823%)
      hue-rotate(162deg) brightness(92%) contrast(97%);
  }
```

```html
<label class='info'>Data info available</label>
```